# How to create a bar chart with one x axis and two paralel y axes in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I am new to PowerBI so sorry in advance. I would like to reproduce the plot below (created in Tableau) in PowerBI.

I need the two plots to be sorted by the values of the first one.

In PowerBI I can generate two such plots, but I do not manage to use the values of the first plot to sort the second one.

How can I do that? 
[Plot with an x-axis that is shared by two bar chart plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYaMK.png)

Comment: You can add the values of the first plot to the second one as tooltips. After done, you should be able to sort after this value. This would be a quick and easy fix, I dont think that would be possible otherwise in PBI

Comment: I have a follow-up question. The problem that I have now is that each plot gets its own scrollbar. Is there a way to get one one scrollbar for the two plots, or coupling them, so that when I scroll in one of them the other one changes accordingly?